# Is this a good candidate for using async await in this C# .NET code?

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, parallel-processing, async-await

I have a collection of objects. Before I save these objects, I need to grab some reference data from the Database. I need to do a few calls to the DB for each object. These methods can happen in any order / are not dependent upon each other.

Can I use `async / await` to make these db operations *happen at the same time* ?

```
Parallel.ForEach(animals,
    animal => {
        animal.Owner = GetAnimalOwner(ownerId);
        animal.FavouriteFood = GetFavouriteFood(foodId);

        Database.Store(animal);
    });
```

That's some pseudo code that explains what I'm trying to do.
Is this a good candidate for `async / await` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If all you want to do is to execute the two operations in parallel, then you don't need `async`-`await`. You can use old TPL methods, like `Parallel.Invoke()`:

```
Parallel.ForEach(animals,
    animal => {
        Parallel.Invoke(
            () => animal.Owner = GetAnimalOwner(ownerId),
            () => animal.FavouriteFood = GetFavouriteFood(foodId));

        Database.Store(animal);
    });
```

Keep in mind that there is no guarantee that this will actually improve your performance, depending on your DB and your connection to it.

In general, `async`-`await` makes sense in two cases:

1. You want to offload some long-running code from the UI thread.
2. You want to use less threads to improve performance or scalability.

It seems to me like #1 is not your case. If you're in case #2, then you should rewrite your database methods into truly asynchronous ones (depending on your DB library, this may not be possible).

If you do that, then you could do something similar to what Scott Chamberlain suggested (but *not* using `Parallel.ForEach()`):

```
var tasks = animals.Select(
    async animal => {
        var getOwnerTask = GetAnimalOwnerAsync(ownerId);
        var getFavouriteFoodTask = GetFavouriteFoodAsync(foodId);

        animal.Owner = await getOwnerTask;
        animal.FavouriteFood = await getFavouriteFoodTask;

        await Database.StoreAsync(animal);
    });

await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
```

This will execute with even bigger degree of parallelism then `Parallel.ForEach()` (because that's limited by the thread pool), but again, that may not actually improve performance. If you wanted to limit the degree of parallelism, you could add `SemaphoreSlim` or you could use TPL Dataflow instead.

Comment: @downvoter Do you want to share what do you think is wrong with this answer?

Comment: in your second code block, will the `GetAnimalOwnerAsync` and `GetFavouriteFoodAsync` 100% complete before the `StoreAsync` is called?

Comment: @Pure.Krome Yes, the two `await`s ensure that.

Comment: AH! kewl :) 2 more Q's. a) Why don't you just do `await GetAnimalOwnerAsync(ownerId)` instead of getting the variable then awaiting that variable? (for `GetAnimalOwnerAsync` and `GetFavouriteFoodAsync`) ? b) can you provide some sample code for `GetFavouriteFoodAsync` .. of course the logic inside can be a comment => `// do logic here` ..

Comment: @Pure.Krome a) Because then `GetFavouriteFoodAsync()` would be started only after `GetAnimalOwnerAsync()` completed. And I think that's not what you wanted. b) It would look very similar to the synchronous version, except your would replace each `CallDbMethod()` with `await CallDbMethodAsync()` (again, this assumes your DB library supports async).